# Using pact for a service with a sequence of requests and responses

Tags: pact

Here is my use case:

My Service is: ServiceA.
It depends on the following services: ServicesB and ServiceC.

ServiceA sends a POST request to ServiceB with some authentication details (username+password) and ServiceB replies back with a json document which has a sessionId.

Request:

```
POST /authenticate
{
    "username": "_at_api",
    "password": "xxx"
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "sessionId": "axy235da7ad5a24abeb3e7fbb85d0ef45f"
}
```

The above sessionId is used for all api calls from ServiceA to ServiceC.

ServiceA requests to serviceC to start a job using a POST request and serviceC returns with a job id(alphanumeric).

Request:

```
POST /jobs/local/start
Header: Authentication: axy235da7ad5a24abeb3e7fbb85d0ef45f
{
    ...
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "status": "RUNNING",
    "jobId": "a209016e3fdf4425ea6e5846b8a46564abzt"
}
```

ServiceA keeps polling serviceC for the completion of the job using the jobId returned above:

Request:

```
GET /jobs/status/a209016e3fdf4425ea6e5846b8a46564abzt
Header: Authentication: axy235da7ad5a24abeb3e7fbb85d0ef45f
```

Response:

```
{
    "status": "RUNNING"
}
```

The polling continues until the status is returned as COMPLETED or FAILED.

Response:

```
{
    "status": "COMPLETED"
}
```

How can I use [Pact](https://docs.pact.io) to test serviceA?

My plan is to use only unit tests and contract tests to achieve code coverage of more than 90%. Is it a good idea, or do I need to have a separate tests using virtual servers? My understanding is that Pact is a superset of virtual server (example: [mountebank](http://www.mbtest.org/)) and everything which a virtual server can do, Pact can do. And so I do not need a separate Component testing. Also, it looks like Contract testing completely replaces end-to-end testing, so I do not need end-to-end testing as well. Is this right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Also, it looks like Contract testing completely replaces end-to-end testing, so I do not need end-to-end testing as well. Is this right?

No. Contract testing is not functional testing (see [this excellent article, with the same title](https://docs.pact.io/consumer/contract_tests_not_functional_tests))

#### What is contract testing?

Contract testing is about testing whether two components are able to communicate.

Consider a contract between a house and a postal worker: The postal worker needs to know that they can approach the house and deliver post (and, that sometimes they may be unable to do this - perhaps the mailbox is full).

From the postal worker's perspective, the contract looks like this:

- Find postbox (with a success and fail case)
- Deliver post to postbox (with a success and fail case)

Note that the postal worker doesn't know anything about the implementation of the postbox. Perhaps there are multiple reasons that delivering to the postbox might fail - maybe the door is jammed, maybe the box is full, maybe
the post is too big to fit in it.

In this hypothetical case, our postal worker doesn't do anything different in those cases - they just fail to deliver. So, from the perspective of the contract, the reason for the failure is irrelevant. The contract - that the worker can try to deliver post, and that they can be successful or unsuccessful - can be tested without enumerating all the possible reasons for failure.

See the article [linked above](https://docs.pact.io/consumer/contract_tests_not_functional_tests) for a more detailed example, but to quote from the end of it:

> Contracts should be about catching:
>
> - bugs in the consumer
> - misunderstanding from the consumer about end-points or payload
> - breaking changes by the provider on end-points or payload

A really nice feature of Pact is that you can test multiple contracts against only the bits of communication that they rely on.

Note that the consumer contract tests only describe communication that the consumer needs to make or understand. A contract is not (necessarily) a full API description.

#### Ok, but why *can't* I use contract tests for end to end tests?

It's *possible* to use a tool like Pact to replace your end-to-end tests. However, although contract testing has a lot of similarities with the features you'd need for end-to-end testing, contract testing (and Pact in particular) isn't designed for end-to-end testing.

If you're doing end-to-end testing by extending an existing consumer's tests (say, adding all the possible reasons to failure to the postworker's tests), then it's no longer clear what the contract means. The contract now describes how the communication works along with the behaviour.

This will cause problems when you start adding more consumers (say, a parcel courier) - do you duplicate all of the failure cases in all the consumers, or do you just keep them in the original consumer tests? If you duplicate the tests, then you have a lot of things to change if you change the behaviour of the provider - and your tests will be brittle. If you don't duplicate the tests, then your end-to-end tests are stuck in one consumer - with all the problems of losing them if you decommission that consumer.

With pure contract tests, you (ideally) don't have to change anything if you're adding more possible reasons for failure that the consumers already understand.

There are many other reasons that you'll have headaches if you try this (your tests start relying heavily on exact data, and the meaning of failed verifications and [can-i-deploy](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact_broker-client#can-i-deploy) hooks would change if your tests are end-to-end tests), but the key takeaway is that Pact is not designed as a replacement for end-to-end testing. You *can use it that way*, but it's not advisable and is likely to lead to painful maintenance.

#### How can I use Pact to test serviceA?

You describe each request separately, using [Pact provider state](https://docs.pact.io/documentation/provider_states.html) as the prerequisite for each request.

Additionally, you may find the question on [PACT - Using provider state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46183190/pact-using-provider-state) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Although this comes late, for everyone who stumbles across this:

The pact spec (v3.0) only supports a single request per interaction (but multiple interactions per consumer-provider-pair). On the provider side, every interaction results in an individual test. So while having a sequence or requests running on the provider side is not conceptually not a good idea, it also doesn't work technically.

On the consumer side though, you have an alternative - which I would encourage not to misuse for end-to-end tests. In my case, I had a class which implemented a template/strategy pattern which involved multiple requests and didn't allow injecting intermediate states on the consumer side. It required all requests to have valid responses.

In that case, `pact-jvm-consumer-junit` (=JUnit4) allows to specify multiple `PactVerification` annotations on a single test method (Kotlin in my case):

```kotlin
@Test
@PactVerifications(
    value = [
        PactVerification("Service B", fragment = "authenticateOk"),
        PactVerification("Service C", fragment = "jobStartOk")
        PactVerification("Service C", fragment = "jobStatusOk")
    ]
)
fun `test successful job execution`() {
 // add your test here.
}
```

On the provider side, all fragments above are executed as individual tests, thus they need a proper state as specified in the answer above.

I got this approach running in JUnit4. Haven't found a quick way to mimic it JUnit5 though.